# How to put a hyperlink in the numbering of a reference in the bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, hyperlink

For example with in a bibliographical reference such as

> [23] The Mathematician, A weird theorem, Journal of weird mathematics,
> 2023

I'd like to make `23` into a clickable hyperlink to an online source depository. I am not talking about all `[23]` in the body of the text.

Comment: Does it have to be the [23]? In my documents I make the title a hyperlink.